# How to check if a linked list is empty in C

Tags: c

I have this code:
I try to initialize a pointer and after i use it to check if my list is empty

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef long T;

typedef struct SortedList {
  T value;
  struct SortedList* next;
} SortedList;

void init(SortedList** list)
{
    list = (SortedList **) malloc (sizeof(SortedList*));
    list=NULL;
    printf("%p\n", list);
}
void isEmpty(SortedList** list)
{
    printf("%p\n", list);
    if(list == NULL) printf("List is empty\n");
}
int main()  
{
    SortedList **list;
    init(list);
    printf("Initialization with succes\n");
    isEmpty(list);

    return 0;
}
```

But i get this output and i don t understand why:

```
(nil)
Initialization with succes
0x2
```

Comment: I think you need to go once again over why a pointer to a pointer is passed into those functions

Comment: You are doing `list=NULL;` after the `malloc` call, of course is going to print `(null)`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is a pointer to a pointer. The actual list is in the value it points to, so you need to dereference it.

An empty list is just a null pointer, so you don't need to allocate anything in `init()`.

```
void init(SortedList** list)
{
    *list=NULL;
    printf("%p\n", *list);
}
void isEmpty(SortedList** list)
{
    printf("%p\n", *list);
    if(*list == NULL) printf("List is empty\n");]
}
```

And in the `main` function, you don't need a double pointer, you use the `&` (address-of) operator to get the address of a pointer variable.

```
int main()  
{
    SortedList *list;
    init(&list);
    printf("Initialization with succes\n");
    isEmpty(&list);

    return 0;
}
```

You only really need double pointers for functions that modify the list. So you could use an ordinary pointer for `isEmpty`:

```
void isEmpty(SortedList* list)
{
    printf("%p\n", list);
    if(list == NULL) printf("List is empty\n");]
}
```

and then call it as:

```
isEmpty(list);
```

But it's probably simplest to be consistent across all your functions.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I just realized the same thing. I've added the explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need double pointer. Initialization with `NULL` is important here. (Denotes the empty list).

```
SortedList *list = NULL;
```

This has the benefit that now if you want to make changes to it pass it's address.

```
func(&list);
```

And checking the empty list would be

```
   void func(SortedList **list){
      if( *list == NULL )
        /* empty */
   }
```

This is usually the way lists are implemented.

---

In your case you simply allocated to  a local variable and instead of returning the memory address you have overwritten the pointer's value with `NULL` - there is memory leak in the code.

With your code it will be something [like](https://ideone.com/helQaG). Yes all that the initialization does is assigning it to `NULL`. This is one easy way out towards checking the `NULL`. At the very beginning making it `NULL`
basically denotes that list is empty.(which is the case generally).